# jquery toggle class on closest span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace a class with another class when a  panel heading is clicked like so:

This currently isn't working (toggling the class) - any ideas?

jQuery:

```
   $('.panel-heading').click(function () {
            if ($(this).closest('span.fa').hasClass('fa-caret-down')) {
                $(this).closest('span.fa').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-right');
            }
            else {
                $(this).closest('span.fa').removeClass('fa-caret-right').addClass('fa-caret-down');
            }

        });
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
         Main <span class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg pull-right"></span>
     </h4>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you include the html with the span.fa elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to jQuery docs, we use closest to find element which is outer/upper to the element.

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

*"For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing **up** through its ancestors in the DOM tree."*

So in your case the span is inside the clicked element so you need to use **find** instead of closest.

Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/4RCMc/1/

```
 $('.panel-heading').click(function () {
     var $span = $(this).find('span.fa');
     if ($span.hasClass('fa-caret-down')) {
         $span.removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-right');
     } else {
         $span.removeClass('fa-caret-right').addClass('fa-caret-down');
     }
 });
```

Or try http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/4RCMc/3/

```
 $('.panel-heading').click(function () {
     $(this).find('span.fa').toggleClass( 'fa-caret-down', 'fa-caret-right' );
 });
```

Read more here: https://coderwall.com/p/wxjljq